# Hide empty results in views caused by entity translation?

Tags: 7, views, entities, i18n-l10n

I have a view generated by [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module and [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module enabled with the option "**Enable language fallback**" disabled. This should mean that if the language is not available the post should not be shown.

So if I'm showing the site in *English* and a post is only available in *Italian* it should not be considered.

In fact, in the view the post are shown as they have all fields empty.

I tried to check, inside, every field of the view

- "**Hide if empty**"
- "**Hide rewriting if empty**"
- "**Count the number 0 as empty**" and even
- "**Remove whitespace**" in **rewrite result**.

In the "**Format**" part of the view I choose "**Grid**" and "**Fields**" and in fields setting checked "**Hide empty fields**"

I tried to apply path 35 and 40, no fortune.

```
  https://www.drupal.org/node/1452820
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THE SOLUTION: after three days, i got that if you use entity translation in the 'entity' mode, you get some option in Views filters. In my case, only the field "body" in nodes was translatable and there was an option, among filter

```
Body's language
```

Setting this to "Current user's language" does the trick.

I heard about an option Node Translation to be set this way, but you don't have that option if you check as translatable only some field and not the whole node.